# TYPO3 change PID in TCA

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am trying to change the pid in my extension. I added the pid field to my tca, it also shows the current pid, but as soon as I change it and save it, the old pid comes back :(

```
        'pid' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'change pid',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim'
        ],
    ],
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your intention changing the pid? The pid is the page id of the page, the record has been stored and is automatically set. If you save a record on page with ID 1, the value of pid is 1. If you move the record to another page, pid will be updated to the new page id.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to set pid like this.

```
$querySettings = $this->yourRepository->createQuery()->getQuerySettings();
$querySettings->setStoragePageIds([$pid]);
$this->yourRepository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
```

I am not sure about the requirement, If I am wrong here, please excuse me.